# Sidewaysfigure can not place figure in the correct place

Tags: floats, rotating

I am using the `sidewaysfigure` command to place a large figure in a landscape position. However, I am not able to place the figures between the texts. All figures are displaced to the end of the PDF document.

Here is the mini-example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{lipsum1}

\lipsum[1-4]

\begin{sidewaysfigure}[ht]
\centering
\noindent\includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image-a}\qquad
\caption{A.}
\label{fig_A}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\section{lipsum2}
\lipsum

\begin{sidewaysfigure}[ht]
\centering
\noindent\includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image-b}\qquad
\caption{B.}
\label{fig_B}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The placement directive `[ht]` has absolutely no effect: each `sidewaysfigure` environments is always placed on a page by itself. Your MWE is very short: one page of text and two pages of figures. Where would you expect LaTeX to place the figures (given that they must reside on a page by themselves)?

Comment: You don't HAVE to use \sidewaysfigure.  In fact, I would avoid it.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429987/rotate-sideways-photo-with-caption for example.

Comment: Actually, I am using \sidewaysfigure to rotate the caption as well as the figures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `rotating` documentation:

> The package provides:
>
> - two new environments, `sidewaystable` and `sidewaysfigure`, each of which produces a single page-size float with contents rotated ±90
>     degrees; ...

So `sidewaysfigure` always inserts a full-page figure at the next possible pagebreak. As such, position arguments like `[ht]` don't make any sense here. In fact, `[ht]` seems to break the default behaviour such that the figures appear at the end of the document, and not at the next pagebreak after the current section.

Compiling your MWE just without the two occurences of `[ht]` results in the expected behaviour: The first figure on page 2, the second figure as last page of the document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{lipsum1}

\lipsum[1-4]

\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\centering
\noindent\includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image-a}\qquad
\caption{A.}
\label{fig_A}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\section{lipsum2}
\lipsum

\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\centering
\noindent\includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image-b}\qquad
\caption{B.}
\label{fig_B}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did not expect that the displacement option `ht` can do such weird behavior.