# How to have a set of "photo" different from the set of "figures", with another numbering and "list of"

Tags: floats

In my document I would like to distinguish the figures into two subset:

- "synthetic" figures like diagrams, plot and so on
- camera pictures

The two sets should have independent numbering, independent "list of" at the beginning of the document, different labels (say Figure 1, Figure 2 and Photo 1, Photo 2, ) and I would like to be able to cross reference both with \cref as I'm actually doing.

If this is is not possible or too hard, I would like at least to be able distinguish the figures and to have two lists of figures, one for each subset.

Comment: https://ctan.org/pkg/newfloat ?

Comment: also depends on the class you're using. Some classes (fx `memoir`) has build in tools to create new floats and new lists of.

Comment: Note that the float package (as opposed to the newfloat package) can have unfortunate side effects.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429987/rotate-sideways-photo-with-caption